# How to update counter in jquery?

Tags: jquery

When I click on the last td of the last row and pressed tab an additional tr is added, but I'm wondering why the row_ctr in this line is not changing`$('table tr:nth-child(' + row_ctr + ') td:last').keydown(function(e) {`the second row_ctr works fine. Pressing tab will only add another row when in tr 15 last td. What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
 var tr_num = 15;
var row_ctr = $('tr').length;
$('table tr:nth-child(' + row_ctr + ') td:last').keydown(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == '9') {
        $('tr:nth-child(' + row_ctr + ')').after('<tr><td>' + parseInt(tr_num + 1) + '</td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>')
        tr_num+=1;
        row_ctr+=1;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }  
});
```

code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rw43V/2/

Comment: There's no `row_ctr` variable anywhere in your fiddle

Comment: my bad its updated now.

Comment: Pressing tab on the last td of the recent added row should add another row, but it only works on tr 15 last td. code in jsfiddle should clarify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see the line:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(' + row_ctr + ') td:last').keydown(function(e) {
```

in the JSfiddle link either, but the above selector won't work as you'd want it to.

The value of "row_ctr" is set at the time of the initialization of the event listener, thus remains "15" as long as the event listener is activated. In order words, even with the value of the variable "row_ctr" gets updated, it won't alter the selector above.

By looking at the JSfiddle, I assume you would want the last table row's last table column to add a new row whenever a tab is pressed. In that case, you would need to turn off the current event listener, and re-initialize a new listener on the newly added row.

Check out the code below for example on how the listener gets turned off and re-initialized on the new row:

```
    lastRow = $('table tr:last td:last');
    lastRow.on('keydown', function(event){ return addRow(event); });

});

function addRow (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == '9') {
        //alert('Tab pressed');
        $('tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + parseInt(tr_num + 1) + '</td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>')
        tr_num += 1;
        lastRow.off('keydown');
        lastRow = $('table tr:last td:last');
        lastRow.on('keydown', function(event){ return addRow(event); });
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Check out the working code at:

http://jsfiddle.net/QTx8q/1/